# Authentication only by one field with two-factor algorithm

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

I need to create two-factor authentication by phone number and sms code. I use **friendsofsymfony/user-bundle** and **scheb/two-factor-bundle**. Two-factor authentication works correctly, but I don't understand, how to do authentication to two step be passed only by phone number.